# Finding time duration when clocks hand interchange position

Tags: linear-algebra

> Archana began her work somewhere between 3 and 4 pm. When she
>   completed her work, somewhere between 5 and 6 pm she noted that hour
>   and minute hand positions at beginning of her work were exactly the
>   same for minute and hand when she finished. How long did she take?

How to solve this question?

Following are the outcome of a google search

> [careerride.com](http://www.careerride.com/view.aspx?id=15616) gives the choices as  a) $7/13$ min, b) $6/13$
>   min, c) $10/13$ min, d) $3/13$ min
>
> [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3510) gives answer as $24/13$ hour

I am not able to solve this question and also decide the right answer due to the difference in the answers I mentioned.

I think the problem can be solved using the below concept
minute hand moves 6 degrees in every minute.
hour hand moves 0.5 degree in every minute.

But not able to proceed.

Please help and guide me how to approach this problem.

Comment: The answer cannot be less than 1 hour, so clearly the choices on careerride.com are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Orol_scambio]

Suppose that the hour and the minute hands are initially separated by an angle $\alpha$.
Let us measure the angles as a fraction of $360^\circ$.
The minutes hands moves $12$ times faster than the hours one, so in the time that 
the H hand moves through $\alpha$, the M hand will have moved by $12 \alpha$, and we shall have
(see the sketch) that
$$
12\,\alpha  \equiv  - \,\alpha \quad \left( {\bmod \;1} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 13\,\alpha  \equiv 0\quad \left( {\bmod \;1} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \alpha  = n/13
$$
With the same approach, in the time that the H hand spans $\beta$, the M hand will have spanned $12$ times that angle, and this shall equal $\beta + \alpha$
$$
12\beta  \equiv \beta  + \alpha \quad \left( {\bmod \;1} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad 11\beta  \equiv \alpha \quad \left( {\bmod \;1} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \beta  = n/143 + m/11
$$
where clearly $n$ and $m$ are  integers.
We want to keep $0<\alpha, \beta <1$, therefore $0< n < 13$ and $0< m < 11$.
To express the angles (in fraction of a turn) into hours unit is just a matter to multiply by the number of hours / turn, i.e. by $12$, so:

> $$
> \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
>  t_{\,0}  = 12\,\beta  = 12/143\;n + 12/11\;m\quad (h) \\ 
>  \Delta \,t = 12\,\alpha  = 12/13\;n\quad (h) \\ 
>  t = 12\,\left( {\beta  + \alpha } \right) = 144/143\;n + 12/11\;m\quad (h) \\ 
>  \end{array} \right.
> $$

where the meaning of the symbols should result clear.
Below are reported some values obtained with the formulas above

[image: Orol_scambio_tab]

Thereby it results clear that:

- the $\Delta t$ can even be something less than $1$ hour;
- with $n=0$ the various $m$ will give the positions of overlap ;
- starting between $3$ and $4$ o'clock and ending betwee $5$ and $6$ gives the solution in bold.

Comment: but, we are not looking for how many times it overlaps, isn't it? we are looking for the time interval where the hands changes. please correct me if I am wrong. so, initially, we have to start with alpha degree (where minute hand is ahead)?

Comment: Don't get your doubts (.. doesn't mean that I could not mistake !) But if you take a better look at the reasoning and at the table I think that starting time - end time - duration shall make clear the process.

Comment: @Kiran: sorry I misread the question. I have amended the table and last conclusion. The rest remains valid

Comment: @G Cab,  the answer given careerbless.com (which I also got using trueblueanil's method) is also right, isn't it? 24/13 hr gives 50.77 minutes which you also got. I am really excited with the three different solutions (yours, mine, careerbless.com 's) and all arriving at the same solutions

Comment: your method is probably more than my levels, but, will definitely spend time and understand this in detail.

Comment: @G cab, delta is shown as HH:MM in the image, you meant MM right?

Comment: the start time, end time and differences you got is same as I got in my answer. Happy that I also got a right answer using a different method :)

Comment: Yes your method gives the correct answer. I wanted just to present a general approach to calculating when H and M hands switch their position.

Comment: your method is general and can be used any of such questions. it is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving between $3$ and $4.$ So, taking the initial position of the hands as
position of hour hand = $3+M/12$
position of minute hand $=M$

Returning between $5$ and $6.$ So, taking the final position of the hands as
position of hour hand $=5+m/12$
position of minute hand $=m$

Since hands interchange
$3+M/12 = m \ ...(1)$
$5+m/12 = M \ ...(2)$

Solving,
$m = 492/143$
$M = 756/143$

initial position: $3 : 756/143$
means, initial time is $3$ hr and ($756/143 \times 5$) minutes
i.e., initial time is $3$ hr and $(3780/143)$ minutes
(we have to multiply with $5$ as M was merely the position. for example, M$=1$ means $5$ minutes)

Final position: $5 : 492/143$
means, final time is $5$ hr and ($492/143 \times 5$) minutes
i.e., final time time is $5$ hr and $(2460/143)$ minutes

So, the difference is $1$ hr and $7260/143$ minutes

i.e., difference in time (in hour)
$=1+(7260/143)/60$ hour
$=1+(121/143)$ hour
$=1+(11/13)$ hour
$=(24/13)$ hour

So, in my calculation, I got the same answer as provided by careerbless.com
(http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3510)

@trueblueanil, Please let me know if my calculations is wrong or not. I was trying to use the same calculations what you have mentioned. (What I understand is, we had to multiply the M and m with $5$ to get value of minutes because M and m was merely pointing to the digit in the clock)

Answer (score 1):

**Simple new solution**

I take it that the hour and minute hands intechange, as given in the header (in the body, it is vague)

Obviously, the duration has to be more than one hour, so if only one of the choices is more than one hour, you can opt for it straight away.

*But even if there is more than one solution $>1\;hr$, there is a much easier way to find it*

---

Let the initial gap between the hour hand and minute hand, at $\approx 3:27,say. =z$ (in hours)

In the time the hour hand covers $z$ hrs, the minute hand has covered two hours less $z$, i.e. $2-z$

Now the speed of the minute hand is $12$ times that of the hour hand, thus

$\dfrac{2-z}{z} = 12$, which yields $z = 2/13$ hrs

and time taken for the hands to interchange $= (2 - z) = 24/13$ hrs

Comment: since it was difficult to explain my calculations, added it as an answer. this is written in the  way I have understood the answer. Could you please clarify why my answer is then wrong?

Comment: I used your method and got same answer as in careerbless.com. Could you please check and help to understand whether I am right? I am now confused.

Comment: there is some flaw in your computation (see my answer below), and by the way, the claim that the duration shall be more than one hour is generally / but not always true.

Comment: @G Cab, the question says, she leaves between 3 and 4 and coming back between 5 and 6. so, the time interval must be greater than 1, right?

Comment: @ Kiran, ah, sorry, I misread the question : I thought she started 5-6 o' clock and was not known when she finished. I will correct the table. The formula anyway is right

Comment: @G Cab, thanks for helping

Comment: @Kiran: There was a typo in my answer, your answer, G Cab's answer and that of the "help" are all correct. +1 to all [can't give to "help" :)] To compensate for the delayed response, I have given a simpler solution which you may like.

Comment: @trueblueanil, thanks ofr providing this short and excellent answer.

Comment: @Kiran: You're welcome !

Comment: Just to complete the picture (so that the method can be used to get the actual times), for $H=3+, M=25+$, the minute hand has come from 15 mins behind at $3$ o'clock to $z =120/13$ minutes ahead, but the minute hand gains only $11$ minutes in every $12$ minutes, thus $M = (12/11)(15+120/13), \approx 3780/13\; or\; 26.43$, and $m = M-z = 2460/143, \approx 17.20$